# How to recover original file content if tried to open the file using f = open('XYZ.ipynb', 'w')?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and learning it from book -'Python for data analysis' using jupyter notebook. I was trying to run the codes mentioned in the book.

Ran `f = open('XYZ.ipynb', 'w')`, the original file became blank after the implementation.

I read that if you use: `f = open('XYZ.ipynb', 'w')` it overwrites the existing file.

```
f = open('XYZ.ipynb', 'w')
```

Expectation was that the code will open up the file but actually it overwrites my content.

Python version: `3.6.7`
Anaconda: `4.4.0`
Operating System: Windows `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand file handling in python. You can read from [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-handling-python/).

We use open () function in Python to open a file in read or write mode. As explained above, open ( ) will return a file object. To return a file object we use open() function along with two arguments, that accepts file name and the mode, whether to read or write. So, the syntax being: open(filename, mode). There are three kinds of mode, that Python provides and how files can be opened:

```
“ r “, for reading.
“ w “, for writing.
“ a “, for appending.
“ r+ “, for both reading and writing
```

**Problem**:

When you open your Jupyter notebook with 'w', it overwrites the existing notebook & creates a blank notebook.
`Ran f = open('XYZ.ipynb', 'w')`

**Solution**:

If you only intend to read the book, use:

`Ran f = open('XYZ.ipynb', 'r')`

There is no way to recover the file, you'll need to download/ recreate the file again from it's source.

Comment: Yes, I have to increase my knowledge of file handling in python.Thank you @ParvBanks

Comment: No problem, we've all been there :) 

It's always good to refer multiple sources for learning. There's a lot of quality documentation available for python. Happy learning!

Comment: Hey @ParvBanks, I am able to get the copy of overwritten file (somewhat older) from the ".ipynb_checkpoints" folder. This folder is available with the anaconda folder. Thanks to one of my friend.

Comment: There is options related to the checkpoints in the jupyter notebook as well: file-> Revert to checkpoint. They might help sometime.